# What is a general name for various kinds of measurements?

Tags: single-word-requests

Kilometere is a **distance** measurement unit.

Kilogram is a **weight** measurement unit.

The Gini index is measuring **inequality**.

**distance**, **weight** and **inequality** are all ... ?

Comment: Uh, "measurements"?  (Though the word only applies to that specific use of the term "inequality".)

Comment: *Mensurandum* seems like it might be possible, but nobody would know what you meant. (I've only found a few examples of this word using Google, all in technical/academic contexts and possibly used by non-native speakers. That said, the following paper does define it as the "property of the concrete system we wish to measure": [MEASUREMENT SCIENCE AS A BASIC RESEARCH AND DEVELOPMENT DISCIPLINE OF SCIENTIFIC RESEARCH](http://www.frollo.sk/F8.pdf), Ivan Frollo).

Comment: 'Measures' carries this sense, but others such as 'units of measurements'. Also a hyponym in 'weights and measures'.

Answer (score 5):

Source:[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/155929?redirectedFrom=quantity#eid)

Quantity, n.

I. An amount, a portion.

a. A specified or definite amount of an article or commodity; a (large, small, etc.) portion or measure; also without of-adjunct. Also (occas.): an amount of something immaterial.

Answer (score 1):

*Measurand* would seem to fit your requirement, though it is by no means a common word. It is a "quantity, object, or property intended to be measured" (Wiktionary). I had wondered if *mensurand* was a word, but as far as I can find out, it isn't.

On a point of information (since we are all about accuracy on this forum), the kilogram is a measure of *mass* (the amount of 'matter' there is in a physical entity), not *weight*. The SI unit of weight, which is a force, is a newton. On earth, one kilogram weighs approximately ten newtons (or 9.80665 if you prefer).

Comment: Yes, and your weight is approximately 650 newtons. When my son was born, my scientist colleagues asked how much he weighed and I replied "360 newtons." They said "No, come on, how much did he really weigh?" so I told them in pounds and ounces and they were satisfied...